# react-native re - ender component by clicking a button from another component

Tags: react-native

I have a list of interventions on my "first page". When I click on one, I navigate to its details, "second page", and there, is a button that allows me to start the events. When I click on that button it fills an object from a route : api/current

```
{
    "interventionSummary": {some object}
}
```

When there's no intervention started :

```
{
  "interventionSummary": null
}
```

When an intervention is started, it should be ended too so if the users doesn't I want to show a reminder message in the interventions list ("page 1") using: if interventionSummary !== null -> display the message to remind to end the intervention.

The problem is that my object interventionSummary is not updated when I go back on my interventionsList, unless I reload. For another page I was able to use :

```
this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', doStuff);
```

But the button and the route used were in the same page. I have tried, forceUpdate, simulate a state change : this.setState({state : this.state}) from solution on google, but nothing is working, I don't know how to make the component interventionsList see the update, or just re render after the click on the "second page"...

I hope that's clear, if anyone knows a way to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your first page create your function.

```
myMethod() {
    //function i want to call in second page
   }
```

in your first page when navigating to second page(in my case when user presses a button) pass a function as a parameter like below:

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SecondPage', {
        rerenderOutputTitles: () => this.myMethod(),
      })}
```

then in second page call this method wherever you want like below:

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.rerenderOutputTitles();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer ! What I need is more on the other way, the button action is on second page, and must update on the first page

Comment: you mean when user presses a button in second page, a component must be updated in first page?

Comment: Yes.. don't know if it's possible

Comment: what i wrote as answer is doing this for me, i'm using a DB in my app so when user press that button in second page, i tell it to read DB again in first page(using this function) and i call `setState` in that function, so when i go back to first page i see that its updated.